# java kinds of type and null reference

Tags: java

In [jls-4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) it's said that

> There are two kinds of types in the Java programming language: primitive types (§4.2) and reference types (§4.3)

and

> There is also a special null type

So basically `null` type is neither primitive nor reference type.

But why can it hold the reference and `can always undergo a widening reference conversion to any reference type` if it's not considered a reference type?

Or it is some kind of reference type in the end? Can it be considered as reference type?

So, what's the answer to the question - `Is [null] a reference type or not` - should be? `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: "In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `null` is not a type but a *value*. Variables whose type is a reference type might have the *value* null, but you can’t use `null` at places, where a reference type is expected, you can’t declare a variable of type `null` and you can’t have a type parameter `null`, e.g. you can’t declare a `List<null>`.

The value `null` has a special “null type” that is only relevant during compilation (and verification) to be able to formulate the formal rule that the “null type” is assignable to a reference type. But the
“null type” is not a reference type.

To add some quotes from the specification:

[JLS §4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1):

> There is also a special null type, the type of the expression null (§3.10.7, §15.8.1), which has no name.
>
> …
>
> The null reference can always be assigned or cast to any reference type (§5.2, §5.3, §5.5).
>
> *In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type.*

---

[JVMS §4.10.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.2):

> ```
>   Verification type hierarchy:
>
>                              top
>                  ____________/\____________
>                 /                          \
>                /                            \
>             oneWord                       twoWord
>            /   |   \                     /       \
>           /    |    \                   /         \
>         int  float  reference        long        double
>                      /     \
>                     /       \_____________
>                    /                      \
>                   /                        \
>            uninitialized                    +------------------+
>             /         \                     |  Java reference  |
>            /           \                    |  type hierarchy  |
> uninitializedThis  uninitialized(Offset)    +------------------+  
>                                                      |
>                                                      |
>                                                     null
> ```

Comment: Wow.. Its a pity only one upvote is allowed per answer.. :)

Comment: In other languages there is the "bottom" type which is defined as a subtype of all reference types. Java didn't choose this approach, perhaps because Java's approach is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it also says `In practice, the programmer can ignore the null type and just pretend that null is merely a special literal that can be of any reference type.`

Therefore it can be considered as a value that can be assigned to any reference type.

Comment: But I'm not talking about practice. So it is not some kind of reference type in the end?

Comment: @user1432980 - It doesn't matter. As *Marko Toplonik* points out in his answer.. The behavior is important, not the *semantics*.

Comment: @user1432980 The JLS says it isn't, but whether it is or is not a reference type makes no practical difference.

Answer (score 3):

`null` type can be considered as a *reference* type because you can have `Object o = null` whereas `int i = null` will give a *compilation error*. Actually, `null` is merely a placeholder to say *nothing*. In this case, your object points to *nothing*.

So, if you call `o.toString()`, you will get a `NullPointerExeption` because you are trying to call a method on *nothing*.

Comment: @Holger - Your code will give an NPE.. The compiler doesn't allow us to *directly* assign a null value to a primitive type. This proves that null is *incompatible* with a primitive type.. In your example, you are *hoodwinking* the compiler.

Comment: but being incompatible with a primitive type does not prove being a reference type. By the way, `int i=true? 42: null;` will work without throwing an NPE. I only wanted to emphasize that producing a compiler error or not, is not a real prove for a formal rule.

Comment: @Holger - Then why do you think  primitive types cannot be allowed to refer to `null` ?

Comment: I think you know the answer. There is no place within the value set of a primitive value to contain a `null` value, e.g. all 2³² possible values of an `int` have a valid numerical value. And the primitive values were created for efficiency, to be closer to how the CPU works and that precludes processing a possible `null` state. The formal rule using a “null type” was created to justify that pragmatic decision with a formal rule. A correct way to say it could be “variables of reference types can have a `null` value” but a type system needs a place-holder type to say that formally.

Answer (score 2):

You have quoted the parts of the specification which clearly spell out that `null` is *not* a reference type. The value of a reference type is always a reference and specifying `null` as a reference type would probably create the need to introduce many special-case stipulations around the JLS.

However, it would be most prudent of you to "unask" your entire question because it is immaterial to any practical aspect of Java programming and is only of interest in the context of JLS's internal definitions. If that kind of question ever arises on an exam, you should blame the author for asking it. As an interview question it may work only as a conversation starter.

Answer (score 1):

`null` is generally considered more as a *place-holder* to to set Object references to ,well `null` to make the Objects eligible for Garbage collection etc, it has a lot more uses too...coming back to your Qeeston **Yes** `null` can be considered a **Special** reference type too